# How to POST a multipart/form data with files in a REST API

Tags: java, rest

I am trying to write a REST API to upload an attachment. I have written the API. But when I am trying to call from POSTMAN, It's throwing an exception.
REST API:

```
 @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(
            @FormDataParam("attachment") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("attachment") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
        JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
        if (uploadedInputStream == null) {
            response = StringUtil.getErrorResponse("eleave", jobj, null);
        } else {
            try {
                response.put(Constants.RES_success, true);
                response = companyService.uploadAttachement(uploadedInputStream, fileDetail);
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                _logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "CompanyRestService.changePassword", ex.getMessage());
                response = StringUtil.getErrorResponse("e01", jobj, ex.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                _logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "CompanyRestService.changePassword", ex.getMessage());
                response = StringUtil.getErrorResponse("erp25", jobj, ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return Response.status(200).entity(response.toString()).build();
    }
```

I have tried as below screenshot but it's throwing an exception
[image: Img]

**Response:**

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: 
Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.

[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response 
com.krawler.eleave.ws.rest.v1.CompanyRestService.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition) at index 0.; 
source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=POST, consumedTypes=[multipart/form-data], 
producedTypes=[], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, 
suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, 
invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class com.krawler.eleave.ws.rest.v1.CompanyRestService, 
handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@7aa399f8]}, 
handlingMethod=public javax.ws.rs.core.Response 
com.krawler.eleave.ws.rest.v1.CompanyRestService.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition), 
parameters=[Parameter [type=class java.io.InputStream, source=attachment, defaultValue=null], 
Parameter [type=class com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition, source=attachment, defaultValue=null]], 
responseType=class javax.ws.rs.core.Response}, nameBindings=[]}']
```

Dependancies:

```
<dependencies><dependency><groupId>cglib</groupId><artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId><version>3.1</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>asm</groupId><artifactId>asm</artifactId><version>3.1</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>com.mycompany</groupId><artifactId>poi-3.5-beta6</artifactId><version>20090622</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>javax.activation</groupId><artifactId>activation</artifactId><version>1.1</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>backport-util-concurrent</groupId><artifactId>backport-util-concurrent</artifactId><version>3.1</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>commons-codec</groupId><artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId><version>1.3</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>commons-collections</groupId><artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId><version>3.1</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>commons-digester</groupId><artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId><version>2.0</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId><artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId><version>1.2.1</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId><artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId><version>3.0</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>commons-io</groupId><artifactId>commons-io</artifactId><version>1.4</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>commons-lang</groupId><artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId><version>2.4</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>commons-logging</groupId><artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId><version>1.1.1</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>commons-logging</groupId><artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId><version>1.0.4</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>commons-pool</groupId><artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId><version>1.1</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>net.sf.ezmorph</groupId><artifactId>ezmorph</artifactId><version>1.0.4</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId><artifactId>flexjson</artifactId><version>3.0</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>ch.ethz.ganymed</groupId><artifactId>ganymed-ssh2</artifactId><version>build210</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>org.mnode.ical4j</groupId><artifactId>ical4j</artifactId><version>1.0.3</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>com.lowagie</groupId><artifactId>itext</artifactId><version>2.1.7</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>oro</groupId><artifactId>oro</artifactId><version>2.0.8</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId><artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId><version>4.1.2</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>com.octo.captcha</groupId><artifactId>jcaptcha-all</artifactId><version>1.0-RC6</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>jdom</groupId><artifactId>jdom</artifactId><version>1.1</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId><artifactId>jetty</artifactId><version>6.1.6</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId><artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId><version>6.1.6</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>com.uwyn</groupId><artifactId>jhighlight</artifactId><version>1.0</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>jmimemagic</groupId><artifactId>jmimemagic</artifactId><version>0.0.4a</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>joda-time</groupId><artifactId>joda-time</artifactId><version>2.4</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>javax.servlet</groupId><artifactId>jstl</artifactId><version>1.2</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>junit</groupId><artifactId>junit</artifactId><version>4.11</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>com.mycompany</groupId><artifactId>KrawlerJsonLib</artifactId><version>1.0</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>com.mycompany</groupId><artifactId>krawlersso</artifactId><version>1.2</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>log4j</groupId><artifactId>log4j</artifactId><version>1.2.12</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId><artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId><version>1.9.1</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>javax.mail</groupId><artifactId>mail</artifactId><version>1.4</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>mysql</groupId><artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId><version>5.1.46</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId><artifactId>svnkit</artifactId><version>1.3.1</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId><artifactId>paypal-core</artifactId><version>1.4.3</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>pdfbox</groupId><artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId><version>0.7.3</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId><artifactId>poi</artifactId><version>3.7</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId><artifactId>poi-contrib</artifactId><version>3.7-beta3</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId><artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId><version>3.7</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId><artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId><version>3.7</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId><artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId><version>3.7</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>rome</groupId><artifactId>rome</artifactId><version>1.0</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>taglibs</groupId><artifactId>standard</artifactId><version>1.1.2</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>org.tuckey</groupId><artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId><version>3.2.0</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>xerces</groupId><artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId><version>2.8.0</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId><artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId><version>2.6.0</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>xom</groupId><artifactId>xom</artifactId><version>1.1</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId><artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId><version>${jersey-version}</version><exclusions><exclusion><groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId><artifactId>asm-all-repackaged</artifactId></exclusion><exclusion><groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId><artifactId>cglib</artifactId></exclusion></exclusions></dependency><dependency><groupId>javax.servlet</groupId><artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId><version>3.1.0</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId><artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId><version>${jersey-version}</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId><artifactId>jjwt</artifactId><version>0.6.0</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId><artifactId>json-simple</artifactId><version>1.1</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId><artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId><version>${jersey-version}</version></dependency></dependencies>
```

Comment: Please format your code using four spaces where tabs would go.

Comment: have you registered org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature?

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Hello @cassiomolin after formatting i am not able to submit the question as it is saying your question contains mostly code and asking to add more details

Answer (score 0):

From the exception, I can tell you are using Jersey 2.x. However, you seem to be using [`com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/1.19.1/jersey/com/sun/jersey/core/header/FormDataContentDisposition.html), which belongs to the *old* Jersey 1.x.

You want to use [`org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/FormDataContentDisposition.html) instead.

First remove the `jersey-multipart` dependency:

```xml
<!-- Multipart support for Jersey 1.x -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Then add the `jersey-media-multipart` dependency:

```xml
<!-- Multipart support for Jersey 2.x -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Fix the imports. And register [`MultiPartFeature`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/MultiPartFeature.html) in your [`ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html) or in your [`Application`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) subclass.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer. I have tried your solution, I am getting below exception.

A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/internal/FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider$FormDataMultiPartValueFactory
2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Errors were discovered while reifying SystemDescriptor(
 implementation=org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider$InjectionResolver

Comment: @TusharPawar Show your dependencies.

Comment: `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
             <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>`

I have changed  `<version>2.0</version>`  to `<version>${jersey-version}</version>`

Now it's saying **HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type**  when I try to upload txt or png file or **Do you want to see all dependencies**??

Comment: @TasharPawar Yes, all dependencies.

Comment: I have Please check